# How to create intent in a class that inherits from AppCompatActivity class?

Tags: android, android-intent

I receive InvocationTargetException and IllegalStateException on startActivity(intent).I have tried using getApplicationcontext() to get context but didn't work.I have also tried inheriting from Activity class and passing context  using *this* in Intent constructor.
Following is the code:

```
    package com.example.worldclocktest;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            showMessage("Created");
        }
        private void showMessage(String message) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        public void buttonClick(View v)
        {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button_list) {
                showMessage("buttonClicked");
                list_cities();
            }
        }
        public void list_cities()
        {
    
            showMessage("city_list");
    
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    
        }
    }
```

Here is the activity.main.xml code: I call buttonClick() through onClick() in xml file. My app gets stop when I click on the button.When I debug the app it throw exception after startActivity()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id='@+id/button_list'
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="+"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Stack Trace from Logcat:

```
2021-04-13 19:56:44.365 10618-10618/? I/.worldclocktes: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-04-13 19:56:44.508 10618-10618/? I/.worldclocktes: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2021-04-13 19:56:44.510 10618-10618/? W/.worldclocktes: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-04-13 19:56:44.671 10618-10618/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-04-13 19:56:44.672 10618-10618/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-04-13 19:56:44.691 10618-10642/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2021-04-13 19:56:44.700 10618-10642/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2021-04-13 19:56:44.709 10618-10642/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2021-04-13 19:56:44.963 10618-10618/? W/.worldclocktes: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-13 19:56:44.964 10618-10618/? W/.worldclocktes: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-13 19:56:45.051 10618-10618/? D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10153; state: ENABLED
2021-04-13 19:56:45.248 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe842a630, tid 10640
2021-04-13 19:56:45.269 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2021-04-13 19:56:45.359 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-04-13 19:56:47.508 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe84203e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2021-04-13 19:56:47.722 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe84203e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe8773730) (first time)
2021-04-13 19:56:47.925 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2021-04-13 19:56:47.932 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2021-04-13 19:56:47.934 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe841ff80, tid 10640
2021-04-13 19:56:47.964 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2021-04-13 19:56:47.965 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fbdda000 size 0x2000
2021-04-13 19:56:48.076 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2021-04-13 19:56:49.818 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=4717ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=11898143064735, Vsync=11898159731401, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=11898171912500, AnimationStart=11898171972000, PerformTraversalsStart=11898172054300, DrawStart=11901127754600, SyncQueued=11901181126200, SyncStart=11901185368400, IssueDrawCommandsStart=11901185452800, SwapBuffers=11902594254400, FrameCompleted=11902864771600, DequeueBufferDuration=1138100, QueueBufferDuration=2256600, GpuCompleted=-2920196950870201425, 
2021-04-13 19:56:49.935 10618-10618/com.example.worldclocktest I/Choreographer: Skipped 288 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-04-13 19:56:50.017 10618-10640/com.example.worldclocktest I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=4884ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=11898176389049, Vsync=11902976388857, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=11902982657800, AnimationStart=11902982726600, PerformTraversalsStart=11902983338700, DrawStart=11902987117600, SyncQueued=11902988811400, SyncStart=11902991070000, IssueDrawCommandsStart=11902991143600, SwapBuffers=11902993756900, FrameCompleted=11903063537000, DequeueBufferDuration=700400, QueueBufferDuration=3259300, GpuCompleted=-7596402803422855178, 
2021-04-13 19:59:19.661 10618-10618/com.example.worldclocktest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-04-13 19:59:19.684 10618-10618/com.example.worldclocktest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.worldclocktest, PID: 10618
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.worldclocktest/android.app.ListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5278)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5664)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5617)
        at com.example.worldclocktest.MainActivity.list_cities(MainActivity.java:39)
        at com.example.worldclocktest.MainActivity.buttonClick(MainActivity.java:30)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-04-13 19:59:20.632 10618-10618/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10618 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the exception including stacktrace from logcat into the question. Your code looks fine, there is something else wrong. How did you start `MainActivity`? How is `buttonClick()` called?

Comment: Post your stacktrace. The issue can be in the ListActivity

Comment: I have added stack trace please help me out.

Comment: *Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.worldclocktest/android.app.ListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?*

Comment: Thanks for the help! Solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is:

> `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.worldclocktest/android.app.ListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Just add in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/..."
        android:theme="@style/..."></activity>
</application>
```